# Grouping by set of 2 columns with switched values (character columns)

Tags: sql

I have a desperate question:) I want to group the data by 2 columns in proc sql in sas.

Here is the example

```
A           B          C
--------------------------    
John      Smith        5
Smith     John         4
Adam      Gibbs        3
```

The result I want is:

```
A           B           C
---------------------------
John       Smith        9
Adam       Gibbs        3
```

I want to group values from 2 columns that may have a switched values.

Regardless of the "side" where the value is as long as they are the same in 2 columns. These are character columns so no least or greatest functions can be used. Please help!!!:)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: No idea how to approach this. Tried to flag records that have same A and B value but then both records gets flagged obviously. I want to group the numbers and remove one of the records for the same group. I want either John Smith or Smith John to stay but have added values in column C from both records. I have been thinking about it for the last 2 days!

Answer (score 1):

You can express the aggregation like this:

```
proc sql;
    select (case when a < b then a else b end) as a,
           (case when a < b then b else a end) as b,
           sum(c)
    from t
    group by (case when a < b then a else b end),
             (case when a < b then b else a end);
```

Note that this can return pairs that are not in the original data.  If that is an issue, you can use:

```
proc sql;
    select a, b, sum(c)
    from ((select a, b
           from t
           where a < b or
                 not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a)
          ) union all
          (select b, a
           from t
           where b < a and
                 exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.a = t.b and t2.b = t.a
          )
         ) t
    group by a, b;
```

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon! It does work as I wanted (second solution). It is extremely time consuming but works! Thank you very much for your help!